# Unable to import stylesheets and components on create-react-app. Module not found

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to import a recently created App.css into my App.js but get a "module not found error"

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Products from './components/Products';
import Cart from './components/Cart';
import {gql} from 'babel-plugin-graphql-js-client-transform';
import './App.css';
```

This is the folder where I'm trying to import:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BeBT.jpg)

Also, I created a Navigation.js component, exported it, but get same error and I'm not sure why.

Comment: I am not sure, but try changing the name of App.css to app.css. Also, can you please check, did you added the default export of your components.

Comment: @sawannirala how do you export a css file? the Navigation.js I imported was in fact exported, but also got same error.

Comment: @sawannirala you were actually right. using app.css instead of App.css worked, don't really know why, but thanks! First time I changed the name didn't work because I didn't 'yarn start'